# Change stuff in master, branch to dev. undo changes in master, but keep them in dev?

Tags: git

I have a git branch named `master` and I made some changes to some files. (No commit yet)

Now I realize "hey, these are some big changes.. I should branch off to a `dev` branch".

How do I take the changes I just made, bring them to a new branch `dev` and then undo the changes in the `master` branch?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not made a commit so you can change to a new branch (it branches from `master` then) and commit in this branch.

```
git checkout -b dev
[...]
git commit
```

Comment: Yep. Changes aren't actually associated with a branch until they're committed; they'll follow you around as you change branches (and if changing a branch would overwrite your changes, Git will warn you and refuse to change unless you force it to).

Comment: ``checkout -b`` is shorthand for ``git branch dev; git checkout dev`` right?

Comment: Shorthand plus occasional mistake-prevention, yes.